# Is it okay to rely on event loop executing fifo

Tags: javascript, typescript, event-loop

I need to be able to await for my store to become ready. I thought this a neat way to do it:

```
defineStore('myStore', ()=>{
  let _becomeReady, db

  const ready = new Promise((resolve) => {
    _becomeReady = resolve
  })

  // init
  ;(async () => {
    db = await initDB()
    // init other stuff...

    _becomeReady() //! here ts complains that _becomeReady might be undefined
  })()

  return {
    ready,
    ...
  }
}
```

So the idea is that elsewhere I can just `await myStore.ready`. Typescript however, is not happy and says _becomeReady might be undefined. Thinking about it I started to wonder, will the event loop execute fifo in this case? Can I just tell typescript to not worry about it or is there a chance this will fail in some scenario? I get that promises don't necessarily run sequentially, but is this just a case of typescript not being able to deduce the order of events? And yeah the `defineStore` callback needs to be synchronous unfortunately.

Comment: You *could* do that. But it's jumping through hoops here. TS is technically wrong in the analysis but also you could side-step the whole issue if you just do something similar to `ready: initPromise.then(() => true)` - you have a promise, you can use it (or derivatives of it) instead of using the promise constructor, to initialise a promise that only resolves when `initDB` resolves which...is the same thing in the end.

Comment: Thanks! That's much cleaner.